# Android studio library iml file forces position in host project

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have 2 projects that I work on:

- An android lib called "mylib"
- An android app that uses "mylib" as a git sub-module

In my project, I want "my-lib" to be placed in an "libraries" directory, but doing so requires mylib's mylib.iml file to contain:

```
<option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":libraries:mylib" />
```

If I commit the mylib.iml to git, this means that it forces every project that uses mylib to place it inside a "libraries" directory, but I don't want the lib project to force anything on the main project.

What is the correct way to address this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your gradle script as a project decriptor, not iml file.
Deploy your lib to one of the binary repositories (e.g. Bintray) and consume it as a dependency from graidle.

Comment: The lib I work on is internal for my company. I don't want to upload it anywhere...

Comment: Perfect, then you need in-house binary repository, such as Artifactory.

Comment: Not sure this fits my needs. I want to be able to open and work on lib files from the project

Comment: Then you need to configure it as a module in multi-module gradle build and depend on this module from your code.